# How to allocate tasks in distributed system?

Tags: java, task, distributed-system

I have large number of tasks and several worker servers. I want to allocate these tasks to these workers evenly, even if a worker server goes down.

My idea is that I split the tasks into several shards and send each shard to MQ. Each server reads a MessageQueue. I want the task to be processed as soon as possible. But how to deal with the situation that if a server goes down, the tasks in its MessageQueue cannot be consumed in a timely manner?

By -the-way, are there any JAVA frameworks that can help with this situation?

Comment: Use a shared distributed queue, so that any other worker can take over the tasks of any other. You shouldn't be managing workers from the top by allocating them tasks. Each worker should come and fetch new work when it is ready. Make a design decision as to what happens if a worker dies during processing - a decent queue system will allow messages to be marked invisible for a certain amount of time. The worker will delete the message/task when done. If it doesn't it will reappear for another to process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is a cluster with shared message queues. As Thomas Timbul said, all the servers should read from the same message queue. If you are using IBM MQ you should ideally install the queue manager on a separate system and have the servers connect so that if one server goes down it does not affect the others.

Each server will pull a message off the queue and process it on demand. Using a J2EE server you can specify the number of threads reading the queue (the number of MDBs) on each server. For example, in WebSphere it is the `maxSessions` setting on the port listener.

If one server fails while processing a message the transaction manager should roll-back the transaction and the message will go back on the queue to be read by another server.

If servers process messages at different rates, it doesn't matter as each server just pulls messages off the queue when they need them.

Be careful with messages that can't be processed as they can cause the queue to be blocked. You need to have a retry count and a back-out queue to which bad messages are sent if they exceed the rery count. These are referred to as "poison" messages and are the subject of other questions on Stackoverflow and elsewhere.

Comment: Thx , it helped me a lot . if each worker shared a message queue and worker just fetch tasks when it is ready , how to make sure that  each server  process the tasks on a average load?

Comment: I am glad it was helpful. Please upvote and accept it if you think it answers your question. I am not sure I understand your follow-up question. Each MDB will read a new message as soon as it has finished the previous one, so it will always be busy. You don't need to do anything except ensure you have enough MDBs (sessions) configured to keep the system load at the level you require.

Comment: Your answer is OK in single-thread mode . For example, if I use threadpool to process the tasks,  and if the threadpool is always not full, then each worker will have to pull the task out of the message queue in race condition. In this situation, How to make sure that the tasks are averagely allocated?

Comment: What do you mean by thread pool. Do you mean ThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: I think this is now getting to be a separate question. But briefly, if you use a J2EE server you don't need the ThreadPoolExecutor. You just configure the number of MDBs for the number of threads you require.